# including/passing slug and pk(or any other variable) in url conf

Tags: django, django-templates

Currently my config looks something like this:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_~\w]+)/$', SomeDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

views.py is plain vanilla like so:

```
class GetDetailView(SomeDetailViewMixin, DetailView):
    model = Dummy
    template_name = "detail.html"
```

and html is like so:

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'detail' i.slug %}" rel="nofollow"></a>Text</h2>
```

.. and everything works perfectly fine. However, what I am now looking for is to pass another variable (such as pk - say `var2`) via the html to the url conf. So, something like:

html (which is a `ListView`):

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'detail' i.slug i.var2 %}" rel="nofollow"></a></h2>
```

and urls.py something like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_~\w]+)/$', SomeDetailView.as_view(), kwargs={'var2': var2}, name='detail'),
```

is something along these lines possible? What I do not want is to include the `var2` in the url itself (because var2 is `ugly`)...

I remember doing something along these lines a year ago, but my memory has let me down again...

Would appreciate any help on this...

Answer (score 0):

This should be information you can determine from `i` itself. So you don't need it in the url template tag at all. so since you've already got to the `DetailView` access it from the object via

```
 self.get_object().var2
```

Comment: The problem is, I override the `get_object` method in `SomeDetailViewMixin` (the reason being I query an external key-value DB).. So, I need this `var2` via the url...

Comment: @JohnJ - How do you override it? I'd hope it still gives you the same instance of `i` that you request via its slug, if you need it via the url then it needs to be part of the url I'm afraid

Comment: I work with Django without a DB.. so I sort of have no instances.. :(

Comment: @JohnJ - I don't think anyone will be able to help without further explanation of this in your question. You must have some way of getting the object since you reference its slug